# Google Sheets tab color for conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use the tab color to conditionally format a cell.  I've got a custom function that returns all the tabs from my spreadsheet:

```
function STABS() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var stabs = [];

for (i = 0; i < ss.getNumSheets(); i++) {
stabs.push(ss.getSheets()[i].getName());
}
```

Some of these tabs are colored as a visual cue to our workflow.  I would like to have the cell highlighted the same color as the tab.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Lynn

Answer (score 0):

To get the color of the tab in the script you can use the `getTabColor()` function for the Sheet class.

See the Sheet API [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#gettabcolor)

The you can use functions like `setBackgroundColor()` for a range to set the formatting.

See the Range API [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)